# Shared APK Signing from Expo

Tags: android, expo, google-play-console, signing

My partner signed an APK, built it and uploaded it from his expo account.
Now when I try to upload a fresh build I get

```
Google Api Error: forbidden: APK has not been signed with the upload certificate. - APK has not been signed with the upload certificate.
```

What piece of information do I need to be able to upload new builds?
or, maybe Im lost... is there another common procedure to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload the APK, you need to sign it with the same keystore your partner did.

If you need to reset the Keystore for Google Play, then you can contact Google Play Console support and they can reset it for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.